# Gradle untar multiple files to different directories in single copy task

Tags: gradle

I am writing a gradle script that downloads a series of tarballs from our repo manager. Let's suppose that I have a temp dir that looks as follows:

temp/lib_x86.tar.gz

temp/lib_armv7.tar.gz

temp/lib_armv7s.tar.gz

temp/lib_arm64.tar.gz

What I want to do is untar all of them with a single copy task into different directories, since all tarballs contain the same static library but compiled for a different architecture. My ultimate goal is creating a fat library out of those, but can't figure out a neat way of configuring the copy task.
So far I have:

```
copy {
    fileTree(dir: 'temp').include('*.tar.gz').each {File simLib ->
        println "Untar ${simLib.name}"
            from tarTree(resources.gzip(simLib.name))
            into "temp/${simLib.name}"
            include '*.a'           
        }
}
```

Problem is it seems to work for only one of the files even though the print statement shows that it processes all 4 files.
Any ideas?

Comment: The configuration looks ok, how do you know that it works for the single file only?

Comment: Well, I know because I'm using the name of the file as the output folder for the contents of the tarball, and I only see one of them being created even though I see the 4 println statements for each file. I'm clueless :)

Comment: It seems that all the libraries are unpacked into this single folder.

Comment: That's what it seems yes. But in this case all the libraries are called the same, so they are overriden and I only have 1 remaining (the last one). Any ideas on how to get to different directories? That would help me a lot, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, have worked it out. In the example you provided `copy` block will be configured once - last wins - and to be more specific the last setting on the list will cover all previous. It needs to be reversed. It can be done in the following way:

```
fileTree(dir: 'tmp').include('*.tar.gz').each { simLib ->
   copy {
      println "Untar $simLib.name"
      def name = simLib.name - '.tar.gz'
      from tarTree("tmp/${simLib.name}")
      into "tmp/$name"       
   }
}
```

Demo is [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/28891097).

Comment: I could swear I had tried the other way around before posting the question, but it does work Opal. Thank you very much!